# Set Video Background Color iOS Objective C Player

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-player

I am updating an old app written in objective c that plays a video file. I am trying to change the background of the player but my code isn't working.

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"Video1" withExtension:@"m4v"];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [AVPlayerViewController new];
controller.player = player;

//add observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:3/255.0 green:163/255.0 blue:227/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[player play];
```

Any reason I cannot set the BG color?

Comment: Most likely the `AVPlayerViewController` has views that cover the main view. Look at the view hierarchy using the debugger.

Comment: You should set the color before present